# Local references to old server name remain after Windows 2003 server rename

Tags: windows-server-2003, email, wss-3.0, rename

I have a standalone Win 2003 server with Windows Sharepoint Services (WSS3) running on it. I had to rename the server and I had bunch of problems resulting from this. Note that the server is not in AD environment.

I fixed the problems with Sharepoint (directly related to a rename) by using steps 1 & 3 from [this site](http://raoulpop.com/2007/08/03/how-to-rename-a-wss-30-server/) (TNX)

Nevertheless, there are still strange references to old server name all over the place: in registry, in Windows Internal database, in Sharepoint Central Administration... Most disturbing problem is that Sharepoint isn't able to send email notifications to participants. This is IMO due to the fact, that Simple Mail Transfer Protocol service is still "answering" with old server name.

When I try to telnet locally to the mail server (SMTP), I get a response:

> 220 oldname.domain.local Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 6.0.3790.4675 ready at  Tue, 15 Jun 2010 13:56:19 +0200

I imagine that since actual server name and apparent email domain are different, sending mail is somehow considered open relay and actual message goes to void.

Anyway, does anyone have an idea, how to fix discrepancies with name or how to fix SMTP server name?
TNX!